Problem troubleshooting error fopen/fgetc file pointer seems to advance randomly
I'm trying to write a basic PE (portable executable) parser, but I'm encountering problems with fopen, fread, fwrite, fgetc and ftell.
Below is the minimal reproducable example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <urlmon.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#define ___IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES    16


typedef struct __IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {
    WORD   e_magic;
    WORD   e_cblp;
    WORD   e_cp;
    WORD   e_crlc;
    WORD   e_cparhdr;
    WORD   e_minalloc;
    WORD   e_maxalloc;
    WORD   e_ss;
    WORD   e_sp;
    WORD   e_csum;
    WORD   e_ip;
    WORD   e_cs;
    WORD   e_lfarlc;
    WORD   e_ovno;
    WORD   e_res[4];
    WORD   e_oemid;
    WORD   e_oeminfo;
    WORD   e_res2[10];
    LONG   e_lfanew; //offset in the file of the NT header structure
} ___IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, * ___PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER;

typedef struct __IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY {
    DWORD   VirtualAddress;
    DWORD   Size;
} ___IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY, * ___PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY;

typedef struct __IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 {
WORD        Magic;
BYTE        MajorLinkerVersion;
BYTE        MinorLinkerVersion;
DWORD       SizeOfCode;
DWORD       SizeOfInitializedData;
DWORD       SizeOfUninitializedData;
DWORD       AddressOfEntryPoint;
DWORD       BaseOfCode;
ULONGLONG   ImageBase;
DWORD       SectionAlignment;
DWORD       FileAlignment;
WORD        MajorOperatingSystemVersion;
WORD        MinorOperatingSystemVersion;
WORD        MajorImageVersion;
WORD        MinorImageVersion;
WORD        MajorSubsystemVersion;
WORD        MinorSubsystemVersion;
DWORD       Win32VersionValue;
DWORD       SizeOfImage;
DWORD       SizeOfHeaders;
DWORD       CheckSum;
WORD        Subsystem;
WORD        DllCharacteristics;
ULONGLONG   SizeOfStackReserve;
ULONGLONG   SizeOfStackCommit;
ULONGLONG   SizeOfHeapReserve;
ULONGLONG   SizeOfHeapCommit;
DWORD       LoaderFlags;
DWORD       NumberOfRvaAndSizes;
___IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY DataDirectory[___IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES];
} ___IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64, * ___PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64;


___IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *parse_dos_header(FILE *fp){
    ___IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *dos_hdr = malloc(sizeof(___IMAGE_DOS_HEADER));
    fread(dos_hdr,sizeof(___IMAGE_DOS_HEADER),1,fp);
//    printf("offset optional header is %lu\n",dos_hdr->e_lfanew);
    return dos_hdr;
}

___IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64* parse_optional_header(FILE *fp, ___IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* dos_hdr){

    ___IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 *opt_hdr = malloc(sizeof(___IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64));
    long offset = dos_hdr->e_lfanew + sizeof(long) + sizeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER);
    fseek(fp,offset,SEEK_SET);
    fread(opt_hdr,sizeof(___IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64),1,fp);
    fseek(fp,offset,SEEK_SET);
    for(int i=0;i<512;i++){
        //debug loop to test char by char
        char byte = fgetc(fp);
        if (byte == EOF) break;
        printf("ftell position %lx\n",ftell(fp));
        printf("%02x\n",byte);
    }
    assert(opt_hdr->Magic == 0x20b);
    long end = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    long end_file = ftell(fp);
    assert(end_file>end);
    printf("Passed the check\n");
    rewind(fp);
    return opt_hdr;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if(argc!=2){
        printf("Specify the PE you want to parse through argv[1]\n usage : ./binary <path_to_pe>\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    FILE *fp;
    fopen_s(&fp,argv[1],"rb");
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long long sz = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    if(sz<sizeof(___IMAGE_DOS_HEADER)){
        printf("Not enough byte to parse the DOS header, exiting\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    ___IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *dos_hdr = parse_dos_header(fp);
    ___IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64* opt_hdr = parse_optional_header(fp,dos_hdr);
}



Basically everything works but on some files the file pointer position seems to trip for no reason at all.
I checked if it had trouble with the file size but it does not. The file I work with is not malformed in any way, pe-bear loads the information correctly and I test the parser with it's own PE file so that I'm sure it launches.
The thing I can't understand is that the file pointer seems to randomly advance (only for certain files, but thus breaking the parsing for some files). Like going from 0x118 to 0x308 on the test file (see output below). The byte seems to be 0xda according to pebear, hence not sure It would misinterpret a line feed, as I saw online it could cause some problems.
Besides after the jump the byte do not correspond to the raw bytes I can see in the file in a hex editor (e.g if I check what my code prints for byte 0x400 and offset 0x400 in file using a hex editor, the byte does not match) .
Output using parser.exe (provided below) as input
Only the first few output lines are provided, for the complete output see links below.
ftell position 109
0b
ftell position 10a
02
ftell position 10b
0e
ftell position 10c
1d
ftell position 10d
00
ftell position 10e
ffffff88
ftell position 10f
01
ftell position 110
00
ftell position 111
00
ftell position 112
ffffffec
ftell position 113
00
ftell position 114
00
ftell position 115
00
ftell position 116
00
ftell position 117
00
ftell position 118
00
ftell position 308   <<< return value of ftell jumping from 118 to 308
ffffffc0
ftell position 309
00
...


Links to the output of the code launched against the PE file
Drop with the PE I use for test and the same testfile again

Since I have so much trouble wrapping my head around this one, the question might lack information, I can add some if required.
The final objective would be to be able to parse a PE but mostly finally understand why fopen/fgetc do not work on this file.

Not sure if this is the only problem, but char byte = fgetc(fp); if (byte == EOF) is definitely wrong. It should be int byte = .....

Cannot reproduce. On my Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2022, it works fine  with the char byte = fgetc(fp) problem corrected.

Side note:; not really a problem, but you should include <windows.h> and drop <urlmon.h> and <winnt.h>.

I can exactly reproduce what you are seeing IF I change the open mode from "rb" to "rt". Either the real code is using "rt" or there is something funky with whatever CRT you are using.

@Luke I think you should post this as an answer.

What compiler/platform/version etc. are you using? Are you sure the code you compile and run is the code you show in the question?

@Luke no need for "rt", "r" is enough to get the behaviour observed by the OP as the windows crt defaults to text. But TBH I don't really get what's going on under the hood.
